# Trying to combine multiple rows of string in an R tibble into a single row of string

Tags: r

```r
data <- tibble(
  x = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
  y = c("a", "b", "c", "b", "d")
  )

dataf <- tibble(
  x = c(1, 2),
  y = c("a, b, c", "b, c")
  )
```

I am working on a table that looks similar to "data" using the "tidyverse" package, I need to get all the rows which have x = 1 to be in one y value that is a string with the values separated by commas as in "dataf".

I have tried to use mutate to get this to work but I cannot figure out how to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Group by 'x' and concatenate 'y' values with commas
dataf <- data %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarize(y = paste(y, collapse = ", "))
```

This code groups the data by the 'x' column and uses summarize to concatenate the 'y' values within each group using paste(y, collapse = ", "). The result is a tibble where rows with the same 'x' value are combined into a single row with a comma-separated string in the 'y' column.

The output will look like:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
      x y        
  <dbl> <chr>    
1     1 a, b, c  
2     2 b, d
```

Comment: I think I answered a few seconds before you, but your exposition is better, so I will delete my answer. It might be more succinct to have `data %>% summarise(y = paste(y, collapse = ', '), .by = x)` than explicitly using `group_by` though.